# getline() and char array

Tags: c++, c++11

I am so sorry, I know this is a basic problem, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere. Maybe I didn't realize the key word. The problem is:

I want to get inputs from user, which will be stored in the `check[]` array, then I see through it to get if inputs are valid or invalid (valid if it is like `SpaceSpace+0000[i=1-5]`).

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstring>    
    void main(){
    char check[7];
        for(i=0;i<7;i++){
                    check[i]='1';
            };
        //int check[4];
        cin.getline(check,4);
          bool cond=1;
            for(i=0;i<7;i++){
                    cout<<check[i];
            };
          }
```

But when I print (`cout`) the array, I realized this: Input is `33`, `array[]` is `"`33`'`Space`'1111"`, my question here is what does the space in output mean and how could I deal with it(ignore, remove or anything).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) reads the input, and then write a ***null-terminated*** byte string to your array.

What you see as a "space" is simply the null-terminator `'\0'`.

If you want to read raw unformated characters, use a loop to read [one character](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) at a time instead (checking for `eof` and newline):

```
char ch;

// Read up to four character, or until there's an error or end-of-file,
// or until you get a newline
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4 && cin.get(ch) && ch != '\n'; ++i)
{
    check[i] = ch;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was guessing but i was really had too few knowledge and understanding in ascii.. Wasn't sure about that space.Much appreciate. Beside, I like your way,and I learned one more interested thing, but still wan't to deal with the old problem cause i'm learning.